# Count size of POST array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am submitting data via ajax to be inserted into the database.

Due to the complex nature of the view and the forms I am sending some redundant information (two forms combined in one).

e.g. the data I'm sending is

```
partner_id:940
partner_ref: 1
product_1_id:50
product_1_quantity:1
```

in my controller I then submit everything bar the `partner_id` and `partner_ref`, to do this I am counting the size of the `POST` array, subtracting 2 to account for the 2 parameters I don't want to store and then dividing that by two to get the actual number of products being stored so the result should be 1 but 2 entries are being stored in the table.

```
# get number of parameters passed and subtract 2 for partner_id and partner_ref
# divide count by two to get actual number of line items
line_items = ((params.size - 2) / 2)

count = 1
for i in count..line_items  
  item_id  = params["product_#{count}_id"]
  quantity = params["product_#{count}_quantity"]

  # had to add this conditional statement to prevent NULL entries in the database
  if !item_id.nil? and !quantity.nil?
    line_item = QuoteItem.create(:price_list_item_id => item_id, :quantity => quantity)
  end
    count = count + 1
end

render :text => line_items # => 2 when it should be 1
```

It must be something stupid but can't see anything wrong.

Comment: post the params hash you are sending

Comment: @NicolasGarnil - it's already in the question?

Comment: You should use the params as array of products: `params[:products][][id]`

Comment: @MrYoshiji - good idea, but noob question alert, is there a way to do that without the Rails helper functions? At the moment my forms are just static HTML.

Comment: yep, `<input type='hidden' name='products[][id]' value='<%=@product.id%>' />`

Comment: thank you @MrYoshiji, your help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters that rails logs by default aren't the entire `params` hash. For example, in my application if I do a search I see the following parameters logged by default in rails:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "term"=>"searchterm"}
```

But if I log the result of calling `inspect` on the `params` hash I get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "term"=>"searchterm", "action"=>"search", "controller"=>"home"}
```

This is because rails uses the `params` hash to store the controller and action name in the `params` hash. As you've commented, on certain (POST) forms you'll also get CSRF parameters added too.

You would be better off looking at how rails can interpret parameters as arrays and hashes. As MrYoshiji commented if you use `products[][id]` rails will translate it into an array of hashes. You can also use explicit array references for position.

So with text field tags (with values specified to illustrate more clearly):

```
text_field_tag("products[][id]", "1")
text_field_tag("products[][quantity]", "11")
text_field_tag("products[][id]", "2")
text_field_tag("products[][quantity]", "22")
```

Your params will contain a products value like this:

```
"products"=>[{"id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"11"}, {"id"=>"2", "quantity"=>"22"}]
```

Which means you don't have to calculate anything, you can just iterate over products and process them:

```
params["products"].each do |product_hash|
  product_hash["id"]       # The id
  product_hash["quantity"] # The quantity
end
```

Comment: Heh, for padding out your comments into an answer @MrYoshiji!

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect your incoming params. You are just accounting for two partner params, but in actual scenario there are could be more params coming like controller, action or authentication token etc.

Comment: I've inspected it in Developer Tools and can only see the ones sent by my form, is there an easy way to see any extra ones, I know I should be sending an X-CSRF-Token but I'm not seeing anything apart from these 4 listed.

Comment: You can see and inspect them in the rails log at Rails.root/log/*.log files

Comment: checked the log, just the 4 in there too

Comment: then you should debug what line_items and other variables have.